# onchange submit but keep the first selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, whenever the user chooses "hightolow" and "1", it normally redirects to `sortby=hightolow&availability=1`. However, if a user changes availability to 0, it redirects to the FIRST of sortby and `availability=0 (sortby=lowtohigh&availability=0)`

I want the selected option to stay as it got chosen by the user (i.e: `sortby=hightolow&availability=0`), what's the best solution? Thanks.

I use express.js (node.js) as a back-end solution.

```
<form method="GET" onchange="submit()">
  <label>Sort By</label>
  <div>
    <select name="sortby">
      <option value="lowtohigh">Price (Low to High)</option>
      <option value="hightolow">Price (Low to High)</option>
      <option value="new">Newest</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label>Availability</label>
  <div>
    <select name="availability">
      <option value="1">Available</option>
      <option value="0">Out of Season</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use whatever backend you have to set the selected value equal to the `$_GET` value.

Comment: Database, session storage, local storage. All options to save the input.

Comment: Ah, this can't be done on the client side? I use express.js (node.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you submit your form, the value will return to your original state (default to first element), therefore any subsequent change will only reflect to single select box, you can let me know what is your backend so I can write a sample code of handling

Hope it helps!

**Edit:** For express.js, you can do this in your handler (I didn't use any render middleware here)

```
function(req, res) {
    var selection = [{
        name: "sortby",
        label: "Sort By",
        options: [
            { value: "lowtohigh", label: "Price (Low to High)" },
            { value: "hightolow", label: "Price (High to Low)" },
            { value: "new", label: "Newest" }
        ]
    }, {
        name: "availability",
        label: "Availability",
        options: [
            { value: "1", label: "Available" },
            { value: "0", label: "Out of Season" }
        ]
    }];

    var html = "";

    selection.forEach(function(select) {
        html += `<label>${select.label}</label>`;
        html += `<div><select name="${select.name}">`;
        select.options.forEach(function(opt) {
            var selected = (opt.value == req.query[select.name]) ? "selected" : "";
            html += `<option value="${opt.value}" ${selected}>${opt.label}</option>`;
        });
        html += `</select></div>`;
    });

    res.send(`<form method="GET" onchange="submit()">${html}</form>`);
}
```

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem as I was facing before. :(

Comment: You mind showing more codes? Especially the handler for this request

Comment: I simply used router.get('/hello', .... YOUR CODE HERE) and encountered the same problem.

Comment: Ah my mistakes, it should be `req.query` instead of `req.params`, I didn't try my code just now (Post edited), you can try using the latest code now

Comment: No problem, `req.query` will parse your GET request and make it into a Javascript object, and what the code does is check for the matching value and add `selected` attribute to it. p/s: up vote if you don't mind =)

Comment: By the way, I think this could also be done in the EJS file using req.query (first by passing query object to the locals of course)

Comment: I still can't upvote, need more reputations. :/ And yes I got what you're doing, thanks again!

Comment: Yup, it can be done in frontend as well, you can parse the query by following this solution: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: yep, res.locals.query = req.query